# Get + Adjective

Tags: grammar, adjectives

We generally use the form **Get + Adjective** when no one else is responsible for the action taking place.

1. The machine **got defective .**
2. He is **getting old.**

Am I correct?
I am not a native speaker.

Thank you.

Comment: My cousin got injured in a car crash; he certainly was not responsible. Then he got fired from his job, and he wasn't responsible for that either. Also, it is stretching meaning to say that someone is 'responsible' for getting old.

Comment: get old, yes, got defective, no. get + a state (rich, old, poor, tired, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

No, it can definitely include things where someone was responsible.

> He got punched in the face

Answer (score 0):

To use 'get' in this way is casual and informal. We can use 'get' plus an adjective whether or not the recipient of the action was responsible for it. A machine might get broken if I misuse it; I am getting old because of the passage of time, and because I am not dead yet, and I am not really responsible for either of those things.

[Get (Oxford Dictionary)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/get)

Answer (score 0):

The verb "get" can sometimes be used as a linking verb, commonly in the expression "get old", but also "get angry", "get hot".  Its meaning in such sentences is the same as "become".

In more formal contexts, using "become" is preferred.  "The machine became defective". This doesn't imply that someone was responsible, so this construction is useful when you don't want to assign blame. But note that while it doesn't imply that someone was responsible, it also doesn't imply that nobody was responsible: "The computer became defective after John downloaded a virus." is correct. In those cases you can consider rewording to make "John" the subject: "John damaged the computer by downloading a virus"

In more casual contexts, "get + adj" is common. Similar to "become" it doesn't imply that someone or no-one is responsible: "I'm getting angry" (the cause of the anger is not expressed but we can guess that someone or something must be the cause). "I'm getting hot" (perhaps the sun is shining, perhaps I'm exercising). "I'm getting old (in this case there is no external cause).  In all cases you could use "becoming" with the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You are citing examples of *passive voice.*

> I'm getting married!
>
> But later he got divorced.

And of course, your example...

> He is getting old.

However, "The machine got defective" is a poor example.  Native speakers would say, "the machine *is* defective" or "the machine grew unpredictable."  On the other hand, we'd happily say...

> The machine got fixed!

Which is another example of passive voice.  However, we cannot assume "Get+Adjective" is always useful this way.

> I got dirty.

works.  But...

> I got yellow.

sounds funny.  It's more natural to say, "I'm yellow."  So, you do need to keep an eye open for the usual grammatical exceptions.

**Just to be thorough**

My first three examples are using verbs as adjectives.  These are called *[Attributive Verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attributive_verb).*  I used the words married, divorced, and fixed as descriptive states of being.  All three of those phrases could also be used as active voice depending on how they are used.

So, for others who might be interested, the active voice Get+Verb is very similar to the previous statements and also implies that something else is the cause of the condition.

> I'm getting angry!
>
> She got tired of waiting.
>
> The cat got stuck in the tree.

These are similar because the cause of the condition (angry, tired, stuck) is not mentioned in the sentence (the man's children, the woman's date, the neighbor's dog), but the subject of the sentence is responsible for the action.

Comment: There are no passives in the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Get**, which can mean become, among many other things, is often used with verbs that describe **how a person feels or the state that person is in.** **Get** has many uses in English and it is very useful to learn the one where it is paired with an adjective describing the state is person is in. I have only given examples below with adjectives.

For example:
**- get rich

- get poor

- get tired

- get hungry

- get sleepy

- get angry**

These are all perfectly acceptable ways to say become rich, become poor, become tired. In fact, **get rich** is more common than **become rich**, which is fine is writing but would not usually be used in normal speech.

However, get defective is not right. **Normally, something is or is not defective,** so if you substitute become for get, it is just as odd: the machine became defective. [buzzer]. If a machine becomes defective over some period of time, I would use become here and not get.

One can spend many hours on **get**. I think it is useful to learn one way at a time.